# Python: remove complex multiline string

Tags: python

I have a file that contains a lot of different text that looks like:

```
Family number: 1
    Names: Bob, Linda, Dave
    Message: Some message here.

...
```

...with hundreds of entries.

Some of them looks like this:

```
Family number: 1
    Names: Bob, Linda,\
    \ Dave
    Message: Some message here.
```

This is due to some upstream formatting issues that is done by some other information gathering module that I cannot affect (or rather should not be fiddling with).

I would like the entries that look like the latter to look like the former.

From what I can gather, the pattern I want to remove occurs on multiple lines. My initial strategy is to search for the pattern

```
,\\n    \
```

and replace this with a ',' because I am not sure that there is some other place in the file that might have the pattern without the first comma.

Usually I do something like this:

```
for line in fileinput.input(['file.txt'], inplace=True):
    print(line.replace(',\\n    \',','), end='')
```

...but this only works for single lines. I also tried:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    with open('file.txt.tmp', 'w') as out_file:
       content = in_file.read()
       pattern = re.compile(r',\\n    \')
       to_be_printed = re.sub(pattern, ",", to_be_printed)
       out.write(to_be_printed)
```

This does not work and does not appear to be that memory efficient since it involves reading the entire file into memory.

Is there a way this can be done neatly?

Comment: Is this [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/mXuUwA/1) close to your demands?

Comment: Seems like your only issue is that you forgot to properly escape charaters in your partern string, see @CommonSense comment for the correction (and his solution also allow variable amount of spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok to read entire file, since you're trying to catch a multiline occurence, hence `re` is ok option, if you ask me.

I assume, that you need some sort of [this](https://regex101.com/r/mXuUwA/1/) pattern. And as @jadsq mentioned in comment section - your mistake is incorrect escape for `\` character!

**Let's look what we can do with it:**

```
import re

#   input block
input_data = r'''
Family number: 1
    Names: Bob, Linda,\
    \ Dave
    Message: Some message here.
'''
print('*** Input data: ***\n%s' % input_data)

#   re-place block
pattern = re.compile(r',\\\n\s+\\', re.M | re.I)
output_data = re.sub(pattern, ",", input_data)

#   output block
print('*** Output data: ***\n%s' % output_data)
```

**Output:**

```
*** Input data: ***

Family number: 1
    Names: Bob, Linda,\
    \ Dave
    Message: Some message here.

*** Output data: ***

Family number: 1
    Names: Bob, Linda, Dave
    Message: Some message here.
```

**Explanation:**

```
,                matches the character , literally.
\\               matches the character \ literally (another \ for eascape purpose).
\n               matches a line-feed (newline) character (to ensure that there is a newline).
\s+              matches any whitespace character (one or more).
\\               matches the character \ literally (another \ for eascape purpose).
```

If you're stuck even with that - play on *regex101* by yourself first, and if there's a problem - update your question with more data and add the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tag to spawn some regex guru.

**Some links:**

- [regex101 - One of many regex site to play with](https://regex101.com/)
- [rexegg - Newbie-friendly regex site with common patterns](http://www.rexegg.com/)
- [reginfo - Another great site about regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text =  open(path).read()

# Replace multiline delimited by \
pattern = r'\\\n+[ \t]*\\'
new_text = re.sub(pattern, ",", text)

# Replace 2+ commas in a row (if that's an issue)
pattern = r',{2,}'
new_text = re.sub(pattern, ",", new_text)
```

Will do the job providing all the matches are the same as your example. For hundreds of entries memory efficiency isn't something that you should need to worry about.